# C++ Returning Pointers

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that will: The function returns a pointer to the maximum value of an array of double values. If size is 0, then return the special pointer value NULL (or 0).

I am not sure if my logic is correct or if the function is returning a address or the value of temp.

```
const double * pMax(const double a[], size_t size){

    double * ptr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
            ptr = a[i];
           }
       }      
    return ptr;
}
```

error: cannot convert 'const double' to 'double*' in assignment
             ptr = a[i];

Comment: Never return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Here is a reference implementation of a similar function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

Comment: I'm not sure any single line of your code is correct.  You aren't finding the max, returning a pointer to it, or returning NULL when size is 0.

Comment: In the current incarnation of the code, `ptr = &a[i]`.  Pointers need to know the address of the thing they are pointing at, not the value stored there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of your `temp` variable:  you should never return a pointer to a local variable within a function, because by the time the caller receives the returned pointer, the variable it points to has gone out of scope.  Instead, you should return a pointer to one of the elements in the the `a` array.

An overview of the algorithm to use:

- Initialize `ptr` to `NULL`.  This is the default value, until it's changed by checking at least one number in the array.
- Iterate through the array with a loop.  (If the array is empty, i.e. `size` is 0, the loop will run zero times.)
- Each time through the loop, if `ptr` is `NULL` *or* the value that it points to (i.e. `*ptr`) is less than the current array element, change `ptr` to point to the current array element.  This'll make it point to the first value initially, and then modify it to point to a different element whenever a greater one is found.
- When the loop finishes, `ptr` points to the greatest element in the array that was found by the loop.  If the loop didn't run any iterations (because `size` is 0), `ptr` is still `NULL`.  Either way, this is the result you want, so return it.

Comment: I tried doing what you said, but know `cannot convert 'const double' to 'double*' in assignment
             ptr = a[i];`

Comment: @Hidden Then make ptr a `const double*` and you need to take the address of `a[i]`

Comment: In the program snippet, if the last element in the array is the largest, it does not compute pointer to that. Because, when the loop ends at i == (size-1), a[i+1] will cause array index to go out of bounds, risky

Comment: "Snippet"?  Are you referring to my algorithm, or the code in the original question?  The OP's code won't work at all, but the algorithm in this answer should correctly handle the last element being the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize ptr to NULL to take care of the case when array contains no element. For all other cases, it iterates through the array, to find out pointer to the max element and returns that. Also, In the program snippet, if the last element in the array is the largest, it does not compute pointer to that. Because, when the loop ends at i == (size-1), a[i+1] will cause array index to go out of bounds, risky. Here's the corrected version:

```
const double * pMax(const double a[], size_t size){
 const double * ptr = (size == 0) ? NULL : &a[0];
 for(size_t i = 1; i < size -1; i++){
  if (a[i] > *ptr){
    ptr = &a[i];
  }
 }      
 return ptr;
}
```